# Counting the occurrence of a word but only once per row (R)

Tags: r, counting

I want to count the number of times a word appears but only once per row. How do I complete the code?

```
library(stringr)

var1 <- c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y")
var2 <- c("x", "x", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "y", "g", "h")
var3 <- c("x", "x", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "y", "g", "h")
data <- data.frame(cbind(var1, var2, var3))

sum(str_count(data, "x"))
```

The result should be 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
sum(rowSums(data == "x") >= 1) # Thanks Maël
# [1] 6
```

which will check if there is at least one value per row (`rowSums()`) and add all the rows with 1+ up using `sum()`

Or alternatively (per Antreas's comment so it is not missed):

```
length(which(rowSums(data == "x") != 0)) # Thanks to Antreas Stefopoulos
```

Which counts the number of non-zero rows with `length()`